# How to get all the values from an SQL Query C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have used String Builder to generate a RAW SQL QUERY in C#.

```
List<string> columns = new List<string>();
columns.Add("id");
columns.Add("Temp");

StringBuilder SqlStatement = new StringBuilder();
SqlStatement.Append("Select ");
for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
{
   if (i == columns.Count - 1)
   {
      SqlStatement.Append(columns[i]);
   }
   else
   {
      SqlStatement.Append(columns[i]);
      SqlStatement.Append(",");
   }
}
SqlStatement.Append(" FROM graph_update");

var ctx = new graphDBContext();
var result = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<graphDBContext>(SqlStatement.ToString()).ToList();
```

This translates into  `SELECT id,Temp FROM graph_update`

And the result gives me

```
id = 1, temp = 20 

id = 2 temp = 30
```

How do I get all these values????

I'm too use to:

```
foreach(var item in result)
{
   item.id =  id;
   item.temp = temp;
}
```

But it won't let me.

EDIT: 
Sorry but I'm not sure what you mean. Here is my debugger

[image]

Comment: What result you've done so far? Try to debug your code while running

Comment: all i have is 'var result = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<graphDBContext>(SqlStatement.ToString()).ToList();' but I don't know how to grab all the values

Comment: What is the content of your result?

Comment: You are just building a query then debug it. Is this content query is correct "SqlStatement.ToString()" if not then you have to make some action to become a true query.

Comment: @reds hi reds, i'm not sure what you mean sorry, I attached contents in question now.

Comment: When you run this code is there any error return?

Comment: @reds hi thank you for the help ! And no there isn't any error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137111/discussion-between-john-lington-and-reds).

Comment: Updated the answer hope it helps. Just let me know if it is work.

Comment: Welcome Buddy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have EF > 6, then the `ctx.Database.SqlQuery`, according to the method documentation:

> Creates a raw SQL query that will return elements of the given generic type.
>     The type can be any type that has properties that match the names of the columns returned from the query, or can be a simple primitive type.  The type does not have to be an entity type. The results of this query are never tracked by the context even if the type of object returned is an entity type.

With that in mind you can do something like this:

```
public class GraphUpdateResult 
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public decimal Temp {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your current method:

```
var result = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<GraphUpdateResult>SqlStatement.ToString()).ToList();
foreach (var graphResult in result)
{
   Console.WriteLine(graphResult.Id);
   Console.WriteLine(graphResult.Temp);
}
```

You can add more columns to the `GraphUpdateResult` class for EF to bind to, even if in some queries you don't specify them in the `select` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation and example!! I updated my EF to >6  and Also it turns out there was a problem with me declaring GraphUpdateResult Model. But it works now !! Cheers x10000 !

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use foreach like this if theres no error return

```
foreach(var v in result)
{
    String v0 = v[0].ToString();
    String v1 = v[1].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```
foreach(var item in result)
{
   var id =  item.id;
   var temp = item.temp;
}
```

in your code above, you are trying to assign the values to the item, instead of retrieving.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ORM-Mapper like

https://stormy.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Stormy.cs

It is a very light Mapper and you can look how it works.

It maps the reader Data to the Object data:

```
public class CatMapper : ISelectable<Cat>
{
    public Cat ApplySelect(IDataReader reader)
    {
        return new Cat()
            {
                Name = reader["name"].ToString(),
                Weight = (float)reader["weight"]
            };
    }
}
```